# How can i set "playsinline=1" in facebook Embedded Video for WKWebView In Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, embedded-video

How can i set playsinline in iframe Embeded url for WKWebview

I also set WKWebViewConfiguration allowsInlineMediaPlayback to true.

Below iframe i load in WKWebView.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F/playsinline=1&show_text=0&width=100%&playsinline=1" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="false"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing *?* before *playsinline=1*. it should be something like *https://example.com?playsinline=1*